# How to update the data in my student object?

Tags: java, arraylist

```
public void addStudent() throws StudentEmailException {
    if (isStudentIdInLinkedList(idTextField.getText()) == true) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: student ID is already in the database.");
    } else {
        StudentDatabase addnewmodule = new StudentDatabase();//creates object for class 
        ArrayList finalarray = new ArrayList(); // new arraylist to store 4 (module and marks) object
        finalarray.add(addnewmodule.addModule());//ADDS THAT TO THE STUDENT OBJECT

        Students stud = new Students(idTextField.getText(), nameTextField.getText(), "", finalarray);
        studentLinkedList.add(stud); //STUDENT OBJECT IS ADDED TO THE LINKEDLIST

        displayAll();
    }
}
```

Output with student ID 12:

```
Name : dsfdsf   Student Result=[[Module Name : dsfsf     Marks :  1, Module Name : dsff     Marks :  3, Module Name : dsfsf     Marks :  23, Module Name : sdfdf     Marks :  34]]
```

I want to remove one the first module marks and add another one to the finalarray ArrayList which is in the Student object. I know how to retrieve the final array for the given student id but cannot update it.  `ArrayList.remove()` doesn't seem to work for this.

Comment: i want to remove one the first module marks and add another one to the finalarray Arraylist which is in the Student object. i know how to retrieve the final array for the given student id but cannot update it . Arraylist.remove()_ dosent work for this

Comment: Moved the output outside of the code, corrected formatting and grammar, made title a little more clear, moved the requirements from the comment to inside the question.

Answer (score 0):

if you know element index, you can do this:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    list.add("A");
    list.add("B");
    list.add("C");
    list.add("D");

    System.out.println(list);

    //Replace C with C_NEW 
    int index = list.indexOf("C");

    list.set(index, "C_NEW");
```

example - https://howtodoinjava.com/java/collections/arraylist/replace-element-arraylist/